# Firebase Cloud Messaging for web: how to send to multiple tokens?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, token

i hope i don't get downvotes on this one, i've been trying to set up web notifications for my CMS using `Firebase`, and i noticed that [Google's Firebase documentations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) on the topic are huge, i mean very huge you get confused.

So far i managed to add the functionality of letting people subscribe to the notification by letting the browser asking their permission to send them notifications, then i get the unique tokens after they accept and store those tokens in my database, i also managed to change the location of the `service worker` and everything looks good and dandy.

Now, i want to send a notification to all my users (tokens) that are stored in my database, **i think looping through them and send a notification using `CURL` to each one individually is a nasty solution.** I can't find a documentation on how to send a notification to all my tokens in one CURL call.

This is my code so far:

```
<!-- Firebase Technologies -->
<!-- Firebase App is always required and must be first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.1.0/firebase-app.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.1.0/firebase- 
messaging.js"></script>
<script>
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyAR84lF2vbnfUWPZ2899dnqiTthgvfv7Ms",
authDomain: "lazemnicms.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://lazemnicms.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "lazemnicms",
storageBucket: "lazemnicms.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "268754114869"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
messaging = firebase.messaging();
//Registering the service worker
navigator.serviceWorker.register("firebase-messaging-sw.js", {scope: "firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope"}).then(function (registration) {

messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);

}).catch(function (err) {
  // registration failed :(
  console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
});

permissionGranted = false;

messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
if (currentToken) {
    console.log(currentToken);
    permissionGranted = true;
    //sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
    //updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
} else {
    permissionGranted = false;
}
}).catch(function(err) {
    permissionGranted = false;
});
```

And also if a user got a `refreshedToken`, how can i know this user's old token so i can remove it from my database after i store his/her new token?

Those questions are really troubling me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The v1 API currently only allows sending to a single token at a time. Multicast is planned to be added (it [was present in the previous API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json)), but I don't have a timeline for when it will be available. So right now that means that you'll need to do a call to the FCM API for each token.

There is nothing built-in to know the previous token for a user. The typical way to do this is to keep the "last known token" in local storage, and unregister that when you get a new token. Alternatively, you can instead catch the errors that indicate an invalid token when sending messages, and remove them from the database that way (see an [example of that here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js#L83)). A combination of these two approaches is probably best.

Comment: Perfect, so i think i would save the token in a cookie and whenever a new token came i can just get the old token from cookies and send it to server to delete it and store the new one in the server and cookies instead.